# jQuery .trigger() call causing unexpected behaviour in Safari/Chrome/Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari, slider

I have a slider, which responds to hash tag changes to move to the next or previous slide. 
It does this by triggering the click event I have bound on my controls. 
When I change the hash tag everything works as expected in IE 9 and Firefox.

However in Safari, Chrome and Opera an issue pops up when the only when right control is triggered by the script. If the left control is triggered it works fine. Which has caused me to be confused about the issue as its not consistent on both sides.

The issue it cases is that the whole slide appears as it its moved by two places instead of one, or three instead of two. Basically as if its moved by an extra space each time. 
The confusing thing is is that when I check the #slideInner it says that the margin left has moved by the right amount, but it still appears as if its moved an extra space.

Here is an example of the code I used.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="rightarrow" class="control">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="slideshow">
<div id="slidesContainer">
<div id="slideInner>
<div id="homes" class="slide"> stuff in here </div>
<div id="blogs" class="slide"> stuff in here </div>
<div id="portfolio" class="slide"> stuff in here </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="leftarrow" class=" control">&nbsp;</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

CSS for the slider elements

```
#slideshow #slidesContainer
{
margin:0 auto;
width:936px; 
overflow: hidden;
position:block;
background-color: transparent;

}

#slideshow 
{   
width: 100%;
}

#slideInner
{
position: relative;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var = slideWidth = '936';
var = currentPosition = 0;
var slides = $('.slide');
var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

$('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);


$('.control').bind('click', function(){
// Determine new position
  currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightarrow')
? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;      

 function
  $('#slideInner').animate({'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)}, 1500);
});

$(window).load(function() { 
 hashchange();  
});

function hashchange()   
{                               
$(window).hashchange(function(){    

  // If hashchange happens whilst in state One
    if (currentPosition == 0 && location.hash == '#blogs' )
             {
    // click right once to slide two        
            $('#rightarrow').trigger('click');     
        }
else
    if (currentPosition == 0 && location.hash == '#portfolio' )
    {
    // click right twice to page three
    $('#rightarrow').trigger('click');
    $('#rightarrow').trigger('click');
    }

// iif hashchange happens whilst in state two
else 
    if (currentPosition == 1 && location.hash == '#portfolio' )
    {
    //click right once to page three
    $('#rightarrow').trigger('click');  
    }
else                                
    if (currentPosition  == 1 && location.hash == '#homes' )
    {
    // click left once to page one
    $('#leftarrow').trigger('click');   
    }

    //..... and so on with more slides 
  });
```

Comment: what's up with `var = slideWidth = '936';`

Comment: fix your javascript there are like 7 errors and 8+ warnings, `{..}` don't match up right, there's a `fucntion` in there that makes no sense...

Comment: Yeah, plus that - at the moment, that code wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, rather than deal with the issue you're talking about, overall, I'd just rearrange the code so that you're not triggering events that way. What you're doing at the moment is really inefficient and will take you ages if you have to add more slides. Something like:

```
// create array of all your pages
var slides = ["#homes", "#blogs", "#portfolio"];
$('.control').bind('click', function(){
    // Determine new position
    currentPosition = $(this).attr('id')=='rightarrow' ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;      
    moveToPage(currentPosition);
});

function moveToPage(){
    $('#slideInner').animate({'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)}, 1500);
}

$(window).hashchange(function(){    
    currentPosition = $.inArray(location.hash, slides);
    moveToPage();
});
```

Might be more efficient.

Comment: i had a feeling that i need to make my code better, how would i pick out specific names out of the array for example it is #homes?

Comment: What I was doing in the hashchange function was cross-reference the `location.hash` against the slides array, which returns an index - `currentPosition` gets set to that value. Just an attempt to make the code more manageable in the future.

Comment: ooh yes i see it now :) sorry about that. Yes definitely i will do that, i thought id try and make everything manageable in the end, but that was an error on my part, i should have done it from the start. Thank you. I am going to start fixing things now i got a lot of errors not that i tried to validate my original full script.